# error when trying to compile jomp hello world

Tags: java, ubuntu, openmp

I had a homework assignment which is to be done using OpenMp, but I'm not a good c/c++ programmer, so I decided to do it in java using the JOMP API.

Anyway, I have a problem running the hello world program. I did all the steps showing in [this link](http://nishantgandhi99.blogspot.com/2013/02/jomp-sample-program-setting-classpath.html?showComment=1366371952530#c4389845337105032522) but I'm still getting this error when I try to compile:

```
java jomp.compiler.Jomp Hello
```

I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jomp/compiler/Jomp
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jomp.compiler.Jomp
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: jomp.compiler.Jomp. Program will exit.
```

I use ubuntu 11.10 jdk 6

Answer (score 3):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jomp/compiler/Jomp
```

In general this exception occurs if jar file is not in runtime classpath. Make sure you have add jomp.jar  (Don't know exact jar name, use valid jar) which has `jomp/comipler/Jomp` class to classpath.